# Writing ID3 tags via AVMetaDataItem

Tags: swift, avaudiorecorder, avassetexportsession, avmetadataitem

I'm writing ID3 tags to a file using `AVMetaDataItem`

```
var soundFileMetadata = [AVMetadataItem]()

soundFileMetadata.append(createMetadata(AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyArtist, "MyArtist")!)
soundFileMetadata.append(createMetadata(AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeySongName, "MySong")!)
soundFileMetadata.append(createMetadata(AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyAlbum, "MyAlbum")!)
soundFileMetadata.append(createMetadata(AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyUserGenre, "MyGenre")!)
soundFileMetadata.append(createMetadata(AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyComposer, "MyComposer")!)
```

Here is the `createMetadata` convenience method:

```
func createMetadata(tagKey: String, _ tagValue: AnyObject?,
                    keySpace:String = AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes) -> AVMutableMetadataItem? {
    if let tagValue = tagValue {       
        let tag = AVMutableMetadataItem()
        tag.keySpace = keySpace
        tag.key = tagKey
        tag.value = (tagValue as? String) ?? (tagValue as? Int)
        return tag
    }
    return nil
}
```

I then tried to write also the year tag, with no success:

```
let comps = NSDateComponents()
comps.year = 2010;

let yearTag = AVMutableMetadataItem()
yearTag.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceID3
yearTag.key = AVMetadataID3MetadataKeyYear
yearTag.value = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(comps)

soundFileMetadata.append(yearTag)
```

In this case I get this error:

```
FigMetadataCreateConverter signalled err=-12482 (kFigMetadataConverterError_UnsupportedFormat) (Unsupported format conversion) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.238/Prototypes/Metadata/Converters/FigMetadataConverterCommon.c line 118
```

*Note that this is a simple error printed in console, not an exception!*

Also writing it as a `String`, as an `Int` o even a `Float`, leads me to the same error.
Same is for Track/Disc count, Track/Disc number tags.

First question is: **how to write them?**

I also have another question.

Currently I've an `AVAudioRecorder`, I found no way to write tags directly to the output file of the recorder, so I commit the recorder file, open it with `AVURLAsset` and re-export it with `AVAssetExportSession`:

```
self.recorder.stop()

let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: srcSoundFileURL)
let assetExportSession: AVAssetExportSession! = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)

assetExportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
assetExportSession.outputURL = tmpSoundFileURL
assetExportSession.metadata = soundFileMetadata

assetExportSession.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({ 
         ....

})
```

Second question is: **is there any way to avoid this double-step action?**

Comment: Your code [seems to work](https://www.evernote.com/l/AFkQrSnCDj5GnKqUaUa5zEHio84Xf7p1SsA) for me in an Xcode 7.1+ Playground.

Comment: @EricD. Are you sure? Note that it doesn't crash for me, but neither writes the tag to the file! Did you checked the file after writing it?

Comment: Only thing I'm sure of is that you showed a snippet of code saying it generates an error, but this code worked for me in a Playground, so I wanted to share that just in case. :) I understand now by your comment that this is not what you actually meant - so you probably want to edit your question to reflect that more clearly.

Comment: @EricD. Yes, i should and I will. The fact is that I don't get an exception, just a message in the console (and the tag is not written). Could you please verify if the file has been written with the tag in your case?

Comment: I didn't test with an actual file, I just checked the validity of your snippet of code because I thought the error message you show was from Xcode. Now I've understood that it's not a compile time error, but a runtime error. I will investigate further when I find some time.

Comment: @EricD. Thanks, wating to hear from you. Fixed the question.

Comment: You're right, I've deleted my answer, the year wasn't tagged properly either, I just checked. I thought it was ok when printing the metatags from within Xcode console, I must have misread. Sorry for the false start. :/

Comment: Posted a solution for the year tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to add the year tag with your code with a few modifications:

```
let yearTag = AVMutableMetadataItem()
yearTag.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes
yearTag.key = AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyReleaseDate
yearTag.value = "2123"
```

I couldn't make it work with the ID3 keys so I thought this could be the problem, and indeed it works with these iTunes keys. Also, the value has to be a String (or NSString), not a date object.

[image]

Comment: It could be acceptable for me, also with iTunes KeySpace!

Comment: Just for reference, with ID3 KeySpace, nothing works among string, int, float or date.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your first comment, please explain. Do you mean you already did that but you're asking for something else? I'm lost. :p

Comment: I meant that this solution is acceptable for me, even if it uses another KeySpace (`KeySpaceiTunes` instead of `KeySpaceID3`). It's OK for me!

Comment: Oh, ok. Looks like I'm a bit slow right after lunch... ;) I have no proof yet but I think you can't use ID3 at all with M4A files anyway. I just find weird that AVAssetExportSession fails like this instead of generating a proper error message or exception.

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember why I formerly decided to use another KeySpace just for the year tag :)

Comment: Do you know about any solution to the second question? or maybe it does not exist...

Comment: In my experience, AVAssetExportSession is the proper way to do what you're doing. I guess you could use AVAssetWriter but in your case I don't see why it would be necessary to add complexity for the same result.

Comment: I asked that because I noticed that the second file - with tags - is a little smaller, about 100 KB, than the one `AVAssetExportSession` started from (i.e. the one passed in `AVURLAsset`). So I wondered/worried about some type of **unwanted** compression going on, but I clearly can't confirm it.

Comment: I suppose the difference comes from encapsulation, not encoding. As long as we're using AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough we're safe on that part.

Comment: Yes, I imagined that, though I still think it's strange that `AVAssetExportSession`-generated file is smaller than `AVAudioRecorder`-generated one. Both classes are from Apple :)

Comment: I'll try to BeyondCompare the two files.