# Swift How do you edit the Metadata (ID3) of a .mp3 file in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, metadata, mp3, id3

Swift How do you edit the Metadata (ID3) of a .mp3 file in macOS

I am writing a macOS app and have been trying for some while to change the wording in section of ‘More Info’ in an .mp3 and have done much searching of SO and found 2 snippets of code that will read the metadata but only one actually outputs the existing keys but I don’t understand how to write new data to any of them. I actually want to write data to a .mp3 file I have created and add an image if possible, as a newbie with some knowledge in Swift 3 can anybody help please. The output below is from a test song (Imagine_Test_Song) I have copied to my desktop.

I found this on SO [Writing ID3 tags via AVMetaDataItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582845/writing-id3-tags-via-avmetadataitem) but I get a compiling error in these lines :-

```
soundFileMetadata.append(createMetadata(AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyArtist, "MyArtist")!) // compiler error here
soundFileMetadata.append(createMetadata(AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeySongName, "MySong")!)
….
```

which says :- Missing argument label 'tagKey' in call. The func is this :-

```
func createMetadata(tagKey: String, _ tagValue: AnyObject?,
                    keySpace:String = AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes) -> AVMutableMetadataItem? {
    if let tagValue = tagValue {
        let tag = AVMutableMetadataItem()
        tag.keySpace = keySpace
        tag.key = tagKey as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
        tag.value = (tagValue as? String as! NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol) ?? (tagValue as? Int as! NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)
        return tag
    }
    return nil
}
```

Second snippet is my code below which does compile and outputs the various data but how do you edit the text and save the changes. Ideally I would also like to add “artwork” as well, is this possible?

```
let homeUrl = NSHomeDirectory()
let sourceFilePath = String(format: "%@/Desktop/%@.mp3", homeUrl, " Imagine_Test_Song")
let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: sourceFilePath)
var asset = AVAsset(url: fileUrl as URL) as AVAsset
//using the asset property to get the metadata of file
for metaDataItems in asset.commonMetadata {
    //getting the title of the song
    if metaDataItems.commonKey == "title" {
        let titleData = metaDataItems.value as! NSString
        print("title = \(titleData)")
    }
    //getting the "Artist of the mp3 file"
    if metaDataItems.commonKey == "artist" {
        let artistData = metaDataItems.value as! NSString
        print("artist = \(artistData)")
    }
    //getting the "creator of the mp3 file"
    if metaDataItems.commonKey == "creator" {
        let creatorData = metaDataItems.value as! NSString
        print("creator = \(creatorData)")
    }
    //getting the "Album of the mp3 file"
    if metaDataItems.commonKey == "albumName" {
        let albumNameData = metaDataItems.value as! NSString
        print("albumName = \(albumNameData)")
    }
```

Output :-

```
title = Imagine
creator = John Lennon
type = Singer-Songwriter
albumName = Imagine
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did I ask this question incorrectly because I raised 2 options?

Comment: I presume its not possible to edit metadata.

Comment: I am surprised that nobody has responded but as I said previously I must be asking the wrong question.

Comment: I am also working on doing this.  However, your commonKey's are incorrect.  You need to look at the ID3 specification and see what the keys are.  For example, "title" is not "title".  It is "TIT2". [https://id3.org/][1]

  [1]: https://id3.org/

Comment: I am on holiday at present but will try your suggestion when I return and update the result.

Comment: No worries.  I think if you switch to using metadata and comparing key to ID3 tags, like ```for metaDataItems in asset.metadata { if metaDataItems.key.description == "TIT2" { let titleData = metaDataItems.value as! String print("title = \(titleData)") }}``` may give you the result you're seeking.

Comment: After two days of research and trying a couple of different ways, it appears that as soon as you try to use AVAssetExportSession or AVAssetWriter to write an MP3 file, you get errors because of licensing issues.  So, it will probably come down to using a library (several are available) that you'll have to rely on to remain up to date, or you'll have to go low-level and write your own code to write the id3 frames and output your own mp3 file.  I am presently looking at the LAME xcFramework to do what I need to do: https://swiftpackageregistry.com/BB9z/LAME-xcframework

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research on this issue, it seems the ability to modify and save AVMetaDataItems to an MP3 file is impossible using the AVFoundation API calls (even though the mp3 file type is listed as an option) due to licensing issues with MP3 files.  So, the only way to do this, as far as I know, is to either roll your own id3 tag editor, or use a library/framework from another author.

I do not personally like using frameworks or libraries from other authors that do not provide the full source code because I have run into problems when the author stops maintaining the project and Apple changes something and the change breaks my apps.

However, I have found [ID3TagEditor](https://id3tageditor.fabrizioduroni.it/index.html) library by Fabrizio Duroni.  Full source is available on github [here](https://github.com/chicio/ID3TagEditor). It's a straight forward and easy to use library.  Fabrizio is actively maintaining the code as of this writing.

Comment: I download project code using your link and have tried to run a demo but have not succeeded so far. I will keep trying.

Comment: I used the add package menu option to add the package directly from GitHub to my project and then imported ID3TagEditor.

Comment: I am a self taught developer I don't understand how to do that. I firstly would like to use an example app to understand how it works but although it compiles in Xcode it doesn't seem to create an app in iSO or macOS.

Comment: I am self taught as well.  But, it will not create an app, it is a utility that you all it's methods.  I'll see if I can update my answer with an example, or find a reference post.

Comment: Actually, if you read the instructions on the github repository, it's pretty straight forward.  That's about as good as I can do without repeating what he has already done.  Good luck!