# How to retrieve music's artist information from app's document directory

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I'm making a music player, which support uploading music files from computer's browser to this app's document directory. Then show all the music in a tableViewController.

My question is that how could I get info like artist name, album name from those music files, e.g. mp3 format? Please help.

Found some solution using MPMediaQuery.artists(), MPMediaQuery.albums(), but they may be only valid for device's media library.

Code:

// FileOperation.swift, get music count, music name & size.

```
import Foundation

class FileOperation {

    var musicCount = 0
    var fileNames = [String]()
    var fileSize = 0


    init() {
        do {
            // Get the document directory url
            let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

            // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
            print(directoryContents)
            musicCount = directoryContents.count

            // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
            let mp3Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }
            print("mp3 urls:",mp3Files)
            fileNames = mp3Files.map{ $0.lastPathComponent }
            print("mp3 list:", fileNames)

            // get file size from URL
            let resources = try directoryContents[0].resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSizeKey])

            fileSize = resources.fileSize!
            print("fileSize", fileSize)

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

// Table View Controller, want to display artist name in `cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "details"`

```
import UIKit


class SongsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var musicCount = 0
    var fileNames = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // get songs number
        let fileOp = FileOperation()
        musicCount = fileOp.musicCount

        // get songs list [String]
        fileNames = fileOp.fileNames
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return musicCount
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = fileNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "details"

        return cell
    }
```

// Update on 8.27, 2019, add code to retrieve music's Artwork

```
 for url in mp3Files {
                let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
                let metaData = asset.metadata
                // print("metaData:", metaData.description)
                // print("=====================================================================")
                if let artist = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyArtist}), let value = artist.value as? String {
                    artistName = value
                    artistList.append(artistName)
                    // print("Artist:",artistName)
                }

                if let album = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyAlbumName}), let value = album.value as? String {
                    albumName = value
                    // print("Album:",albumName)
                }

                if let albumImage = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyArtwork}), let value = albumImage.value as? Data {
                    albumArtWork = UIImage(data: value)
                    artWorkList.append(albumArtWork!)
                } else {
                    print("artWork is not found!")
                }
            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263980/id3-tags-with-swift may help

Comment: This blog article has some interesting info and is in Swift: https://www.fabrizioduroni.it/2018/05/08/id3tageditor-swift-read-write-id3-tag-mp3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the MP3 tags with `AVKit`

```
import AVKit

let mp3Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }
for url in mp3Files {   
    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let metaData = asset.metadata
    if let artist = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyArtist}), let value = artist.value as? String {
        print("Artist:",value)
    }
    if let album = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyAlbumName}), let value = album.value as? String {
        print("Album:",value)
    }
}
```

Comment: using AVKit solves my problem, thanks:) I add every music's artist to a list `artistList.append(String(artistName! as! Substring))` (a bit pussy coding here) in fileOperation.swift, the artist.value is a type of NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol, what...I need to convert it to String as the labelText in TableView need String. And for 1st solution you provided, Xcode said it cannot find func like `MDItemCreateWithURL` after importing coreServices, so I guess it is for Mac OSX only but not iOS.

Comment: Please, `String(artistName! as! Substring)` is nonsense. I updated the answer with a better way to cast the type. And I removed the CoreFoundation suggestion because I overlooked the `ios` tag.

Comment: Well, that is suggest by Xcode, haha. I implemented ur change on my code, and it is working on my iPhone. As a rookie of Swift, I'm not so familiar with those `?`, `!` symbols usage, I guess `artist.value as? String` convert `artist.value` to an optional String which could be with value or nil, anyway I will google those usage, could be basic grammar.

Comment: Rather than googling read [Language Guide: The Basics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

Comment: As I got some experience on Python & Java, I just get a bit overview on Swift official playground which is really short then decide to learn it in the practicing via create a Music Player app. I should read this Basics guide! Since your solution solve my problem, I will put it as the answer, thanks for the quick reply.